# How to access property dynamically inside nested object for sorting in Vue 3?

Tags: json, sorting, vuejs3

I am trying to sort table by dynamically selecting property.
I have an object list:

```
Products : {id: 1, Name: 'Ball', CategoryId: 1, Category: {id:1, Name:'Toy'}, Price:2},
          {id: 2, Name: 'Plane', CategoryId: 1, Category: {id:1, Name:'Toy'}, Price:5},
          {id: 3, Name: 'Ruler', CategoryId: 2, Category: {id:2, Name:'SchoolSupplies'}, Price:1},
          {id: 4, Name: 'Pencil', CategoryId: 2, Category: {id:2, Name:'SchoolSupplies'}, Price:1},
          {id: 2, Name: 'Balloon', CategoryId: 1, Category: {id:1, Name:'Toy'}, Price:5},
```

Now I am trying to sort table by sending propertyname like this:

```
@click="sortBy='Name'" etc



return Products.sort((a, b) => {
                                var a = a[sortBy] ? a[sortBy].toLowerCase() : a[sortBy];
                                var b = b[sortBy] ? b[sortBy].toLowerCase() : b[sortBy];
                                return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1;
                            });
```

Sort function is working for properties other than nested properties.
So my question is what do I pass on click to access Category.Name?

I tried @click="sortBy='Category.Name'"  doesn't work, @click="sortBy='Category[Name]'" doesn't work, @click="sortBy='Category[0].Name'"  doesn't work,

Comment: In all tried cases, values show undefined inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the sort function dynamically:

```
const sortFn = new Function('a, b', `
  a = (a.${sortBy} || '').toLowerCase();
  b = (b.${sortBy} || '').toLowerCase();
  return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1;
`);

return Products.sort(sortFn);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This does not address my question. Your solution just refines use of empty. Also, gives syntax error. My question is what shoul be passed to sortBy if I want to sort by category name.

Comment: @user1744582 look closer